# Cannot convert value of type'[AnyObject]'to expected argument type '[UIViewController]?'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

```
private func createPageViewController() {
    let pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    pageViewController.dataSource = self
    pageViewController.delegate = self

    if contentImages.count > 0 {
        let firstVC = self.getItemController(0)!
        let startingVCs: NSArray = [firstVC]
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(startingVCs as [AnyObject] as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Check with `pageViewController.setViewControllers(startingVCs as [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers(startingVCs as [AnyObject] as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

into

The `viewControllers` parameter is now a `[UIViewController]`. So your `viewControllers` array that you pass in must be `[UIViewController]`.

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers(startingVCs as [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```